# incompatible types of assignment of int to int [x]

Tags: c++

So there is a matrix of n lines and m columns, x y are coordonates for a the tree that was first on fire. Figure out how many days until the hole forest is burnt down.

I think I got the code down but there is a problem with it.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n,m,p[5][5],x,y,z=1,c,a=1,b=1;
    cout<<"Cate linii de copaci sunt:";
    cin>>n;
    cout<<"Cate coloane de copaci sunt:";
    cin>>m;
    cout<<"Coordonata X a copacului de la care a izbucnit focul:";
    cin>>x;
    cout<<"Coordonata Y a copacului de la care a izbucnit focul:";
    cin>>y;
    p[x][y]=1;
        while (c!=0) {
            c=0;
            if (b!=0) {
                    b=0;
            if (x+a<=n) {
                 p[x+a]=1;
                 b++;
            }
             if (x-a<=n) {
                 p[x-a]=1;
                 b++;
            }
             if (y+a<=m) {
                 p[x+a]=1;
                 b++;
            }
             if (y-a<=m) {
                 p[x-a]=1;
                 b++;
            }
            c=1;
            z++;
            }
            a++;
        }
        cout<<"In total a durat "<<z<<" zile ca sa arda toata padurea.";
    return 0;

}
```

At every if p[x/y -/+ a]=1 there is this error:
incompatible types in assignment of int to int[5]

If anyone could help me understand what have I done wrong for this error to show up. And also if there is a better solution than the one I have wrote I would appriciate to see it.
I know it is probably an easy error but I'm still at the beginning of my coding career.

Thanks for helping/reading! Have a nice day !

When I declared the Matrix.. if If I change the columns and lines to another value, the error will show up incompatible types in assignment of int to int[that value that I've put in declaration]

Uhm, haven't really expected anything because I am learning but the results I was hoping for were to not have this error, maybe a different error I would have known to solve but never saw this one.

Comment: `p[x+a]` is a row in your 2D array and you are trying to assign a single number. What are you trying to do here?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Concerning your problem, also extract a [mcve]. Further, one note: Check the description of tags that you apply to your question, in particular the "c" tag is misplaced here!

Comment: Also read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for tips on debugging your code.

Comment: Maybe you want `p[x+a][y] = 1`?

Answer (score 2):

`p[5][5]` declares a two dimensional array, or matrix, as you state. When you want to insert a value, you have to specify the location in both dimensions, e.g. `p[1][2]`. Currently you only specify one dimension with `p[x+a]`, which refers to a row in the matrix, which can also be comprehended as a pointer to a 1-dimensional matrix. Thus, the error about assigning an `int` to an `int[5]`, because you are attempting to assign an `int` to a row in the matrix.

Answer (score 0):

When you are defining a 2D array the start point (the array name) is actually int** 
So, when you dereference once with p[x-a] the type is actually int* and not int.
therefore if you are trying to set this with an int variable you will get 'incompatible types'

Comment: A 2d `int` array is not a `int**`.  They are completely different things.  A 2d `int` array decays into a `int(*)[N]`